# MySQL проверить наличие данных в одной из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется две таблицы - `messages` и `comments`. В одной из этих таблиц есть строка, у которой `content == 'hello'`. Нам нужно знать в какой из таблиц есть эта строка (значение уникально) и получить `user_name` для этой строки. То есть, из базы мы должны получить такой ответ, который позволил бы нам однозначно идентифицировать из какой таблицы этот ответ получен. Человеческим языком - какой пользователь данный контент опубликовал, и было это сообщением или комментарием. Желательно это сделать одним запросом. Я пробовал делать через UNION, но что-то либо знаний не хватает (мускул не мой конёк), либо руки из задницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT author_name, 'messages' tablename 
    FROM messages 
    WHERE content = 'hello'
UNION
    SELECT author_name, 'comments' 
    FROM comments 
    WHERE content = 'hello';
```

Answer (score 1):

Магия. Стоило только отправить вопрос на StackOverflow, всё получилось. Сделал так:

```
SELECT messages.author_name as messages_author_name FROM messages WHERE messages.content = 'hello'
UNION
SELECT comments.author_name as comments_author_name FROM comments WHERE comments.content = 'hello';
```

Желаемый результат достигнут.

Comment: Не достигнут. У Вас всегда колонка будет называться `messages_author_name`, и определить в какой из таблиц встретилось искомое, не удастся.

Comment: @Yaant да, действительно, правда Ваша, недоглядел. Как правильно сделать?

Comment: @Yaant Благодарю. Всё работает как нужно

Comment: `SELECT ..., 'messages' AS table_name FROM ...`